# Generate a list in Haskell using comprehensions by filtering sequences each two numbers

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'd like to perform the following list in haskell using comprehensions:

```hs
[1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18]
```

I've tried this:

```hs
[x | x <- [1..18], y <- [1..4], y < 3]
```

but I get this:

```hs
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18]
```

I don't know if I could use some Enum function to get the list, but I wonder if there is some way to do it with list comprehensions. I can see I'm getting one x for each y value, but I only want the y values to the filter, not for the first list generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want this:

```
Prelude> [x+y | x <- [1, 5..18], y <- [0..1]]
[1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18]
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank yout a lot. Now I'm trying to undestand why your code works (Newbie in Haskell)

Comment: @mdasilva `x` is being taken from the list `[1, 5, 9, 13, 17]`, and `y` is being taken from the list `[0, 1]`. Since the result is `x+y` for each pair of `x` and `y`, the final list is `[1+0, 1+1, 5+0, 5+1, 9+0, 9+1, 13+0, 13+1, 17+0, 17+1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
[x | x <- [1..18], x rem 4 < 2]
```

**EDIT**

correct solution is

```
 [x + 1 | x <- [0..17], x `rem` 4 < 2]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to use `\`` in `\`rem\``, and this do not provide the expected output.

Comment: Thank you a lot but this code generate the following list
```
[1,4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17]
```

Comment: `[ x | x <- [1..18], y <- [1,2], x \`mod\` 4 == y]` is close to the original comprehension

Comment: Fixed my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the list comprehension, it's just

```
-- [1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18] == [1,2] ++ [5,6] ++ [9,10] ++ ...
--                            == [1+0,1+1] ++ [5+0,5+1] ++ [9+0,9+1] ++ ...
concatMap (\x -> [x, x+1]) [1,5..18]
```

or

```
[1,5..18] >>= \x -> [x, x+1]
```

Translating back to a list comprehension, you get [@NetWave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760581/1126841) (via `[1,5..18] >>= \x -> [0..1] >>= \y -> [x + y]`)

Answer (score 0):

It's repeating additions of 1 and 3 to previous values so perhaps list comprehension is not the best solution. You've already got perfect answers.

This is also lazy which is usually way more useful.

```
scanl (+) 1 $ cycle [1,3]

take 25 $ scanl (+) 1 $ cycle [1,3]
```

[1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34,37,38,41,42,45,46,49]

**1.29.2021 A list comprehension version**

Formulas can do just about anything. They supersede logic, even.
This formula amazed me as I cam upon it. I want to generalize it for other purposes. I have been reading the last year about how to survive covid with hundreds of papers and micro-biology and immunology books. I am fascinated.
Here's the list comprehension version.

```
[ ((n*2)+(mod n 2))-2 | n <- [1..26] ]
```

[1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34,37,38,41,42,45,46,49,50]

The length of the output list is 26, the final value is almost exactly twice 26.